# global on_message callback firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

In my app, I have configured firebase push notification and I have the configuration code as follows. It shows onMessage on the page where I have implemented this code in `initState`. I have multipage form fields in the app and I want alert to show while on any page within the app. Is there any way to show an alert in every screen without calling the function in `initState` on every page?

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        content: ListTile(
                        title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
                        subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
                        ),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                            child: Text('Ok'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            );
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final notification = message['notification'];
        setState(() {
          messages.add(Message(
              title: notification['title'], body: notification['body']));
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");

        final notification = message['data'];
        setState(
          () {
            messages.add(
              Message(
                title: '${notification['title']}',
                body: '${notification['body']}',
              ),
            );
          },
        );
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notify');
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call FCM configure only once or you will run into problems (my experience anyway). If you call .configure in the initState of your home screen, any pages that are lower down the tree (subordinate) and that you navigate to and return from, will react to FCM notifications via the onMessage callback.